# DropNet compatibility with DropBox API v2

Tags: .net, dropbox, dropnet

Is dropnet compatible with latest DropBox API, i.e. V2?
It's not safe if it's using Sync API which is deprecated and is going to be shutdown, soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last commit I see for [DropNet](https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet) is from April of 2015, which predates the release of Dropbox API v2. It uses Core API v1.

See https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/... I think you may be confused about what happened when? (The API being turned off soon is the Datastore API.)

Comment: Yes, confused, API v1 will stay alive or deprecate soon?

Comment: API v1 will be deprecated at some point, but the team hasn't announced a timeline.

Comment: So I'll use official API (https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet) , though a little complicated!

Answer (score 0):

API v1 is being deprecated as well. See [dropbox blog post](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/)

I hope the developer adds support for API v2 soon.